# If column2 is NA join on column1 else join on column1 and column2

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't find the answer for the life of me. I want to use dplyr to join two tibbles together. If the second column is NA then just join on the first column. If the second column is not NA, then join on the first and second column. The solution below doesn't work, but it's what I'm trying to do.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble(x = c("Name", "City", "City"),  y = c("Table5", "Table1", "Table2"))
df2 <- tibble(x2 = c("Name", "City", "City"), y2 = c(NA, "Table1", "Table2"), z = c("a", "b", "c"))

joined_data <- if (is.na(df2$y2)) {
  df1 %>% 
    left_join(df2, by = c("x" = "x2"))
} else {
  df1 %>% 
    left_join(df2, by = c("x" = "x2", "y" = "y2")) 
}
```

The final result should be

```
  x     y      z    
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 Name  Table5 a  
2 City  Table1 b    
3 City  Table2 c
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap with `any` i.e. `if(any(is.na(df2$y2))`.  BTW, when you join only by the 'x' column,if both the dataset 'x's have duplicate elements, it will result in duplicate rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first find all the `NA` indices and then join them in two separate calls. For non-NA indices we join them on `x` and `y` whereas for NA indices we join them on only `x` and select non-NA value between `y` and `y2` using `coalesce` and then bind the rows together.

```
library(tidyverse)
NAinds <- is.na(df2$y2)

df1[!NAinds,] %>%
   left_join(df2, by = c("x" = "x2", "y" = "y2")) %>%
   bind_rows(df1[NAinds, ]  %>%
                 left_join(df2,  by = c("x" = "x2")) %>%
                 mutate(y = coalesce(y, y2)) %>%
                 select(-y2))


#   x     y      z    
# <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#1 City  Table1 b    
#2 City  Table2 c    
#3 Name  Table5 a
```

Comment: @JennaAllen I noticed that you unaccepted the answer after accepting it. Are you looking for something else ?

Comment: No, sorry. I was looking at it on my phone and must have accidentally clicked it.